# Programmatically add a page to Confluence using CLI and macro

Tags: confluence

I am trying to migrate our mediawiki to confluence. We tried usin Universal Wiki Converter, but the it exports HTML content, for which we have to manually use HTML macro inside the conflence. Obviously we can't do that manually for each page in our wiki. I used conflunec cli's function:

```
confluence --action convertToStorageFormat --space "ITWP" --title "test001" --content "{html}bodytext{html}"   --server  --user  --password
```

it spits out something like this:

```
<ac:structured-macro ac:name="html"><ac:plain-text-body><![CDATA[bodytext]]></ac:plain-text-body></ac:structured-macro>
```

Which is again not recognized by confluence.

Is there any way I can just send HTML content to Confluence and it uses HTML macro to parse and display like a standard page like it was before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is the confluence stodge format the:

```
<ac:structured-macro ac:name="html">
```

is the html-macro start tag and so on.
if you install the "Source Editor" plugin you should be able to input the:

```
<ac:structured-macro ac:name="html">
  <ac:plain-text-body>
    <![CDATA[bodytext]]>
  </ac:plain-text-body>
</ac:structured-macro>
```

into it and you will get our contents on the confluence page (previewed the html-macro plugin installed)